# Omnipay returns a null Itembag

Tags: omnipay, craftcms

I am trying to return the items in my order to send it for payment as such:

```
$orderItems = $this->getItems();
```

But the `$orderItems` is always null. I tried this with an offsite gateway, onsite gateway, it is always null. I am using it in Craft's Commerce 2.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets stuck here, I found out what I missed.
I forgot to set the `$sendCartInfo` to true in my gateway. So my gateway is now like this:

```
<?php

namespace onegr\mine\Gateways;

use ...;

class Gateway extends CreditCardGateway
{
    public $sendCartInfo = true;

    }
    protected function createGateway(): AbstractGateway
    {
        /** @var OmnipayGateway $gateway */
        $gateway = Omnipay::create($this->getGatewayClassName());
        return $gateway;
    }
    protected function getGatewayClassName()
    {
        return '\\'.OmnipayGateway::class;
    }
}
```